# Validações que dependam do banco utilizando o Flunt

Tags: c#, cqrs

Estamos utilizando o Flunt e ficamos na dúvida de como fazer uma notificação a partir de uma validação que necessite ir ao banco. Fizemos uma implementação e gostaríamos de ver qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso:
Por exemplo, vamos supor a seguinte regra: Não se pode cadastrar código repetido.

1. No handle, chamamos o método Validate, passando como parâmetro a interface do repositório que será consultado:

`command.Validate(_testeRepository);`

2. No command, no método Validate, chamamos o AddNotifications com a classe contrato passando também a interface do repositório que será consultado:

   ```
   public void Validate(ITesteRepository testeRepository)
   {
       AddNotifications(new CriarTesteCommandContract(this, testeRepository));
   }
   ```
3. Criamos uma classe para consultar o banco via repositório e verificar se o código informado já existe.  O método IsValid() retorna o resultado. Fizemos isso pois iremos utilizar essa validação na alteração também:

```
public class ExisteCodigo 
    { 
        private string _codigo; 
        private ITesteRepository _testeRepository; 

        public ExisteCodigo( 
            string codigo, 
            ITesteRepository testeRepository) 
        { 
            _codigo = codigo; 
            _testeRepository = testeRepository; 
        } 
        public async Task<bool> IsValid()
        {
            var teste = await _testeRepository.GetByCodigoAsync(_codigo);
            return teste is not null;
        }
    }
```

4. Na classe contrato, no método ValidateAsync, chamamos a classe criada acima para verificar a condição do código no banco. Daí, adicionamos a notificação ou não, de acordo com o resultado:

```
public CriarTesteCommandContract ( 
            CriarTesteCommand criarTesteCommand, 
            ITesteRepository testeRepository) 
        { 
            Requires() 
                .IsNotEmpty(criarTesteCommand.Codigo, "Codigo", "Código é obrigatório") 
            _ = ValidateAsync(criarTesteCommand, testeRepository); 
        } 

        private async Task ValidateAsync( 
            CriarTesteCommand criarTesteCommand, 
            ITesteRepository testeRepository) 
        { 
            var existeCodigo = await new ExisteCodigo(
                   criarTesteCommand.Codigo,
                   testeRepository)
                   .IsValid(); 
            Requires() 
                .IsFalse(existeCodigo, "Codigo", "Já existe código cadastrado"); 
        }
```

**Existe uma melhor maneira de implementar validações que dependam do banco?**

Answer (score -1):

não conheço muito o Flunt, mas na nova versão você pode herdar e criar uma nova condição?
por exemplo:

.Requires()
.NotExistsInRepo(Item, repo, condition, "item", "Item already exists")